# Is it possible to know from which folder cucumber scenario is running?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I have next folder structure:

```
-features
  -admin
  -desktop
  -mobile
-step definitions
-support
```

I want to know from which folder current scenario is running now (admin / desktop / mobile).
Is it possible?
Because I want to add a condition into *hooks* file for execute needed conditions of different folders.

Comment: What’s wrong with plain old good `__FILE__`?

Comment: It puts only hooks file name. And I need to detect from which folder scenario was run. 'cause I want to detect it in hooks file in Before method. Is it possible to do like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access details about the feature file location using the [`Scenario#location`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cucumber-core/Cucumber/Core/Test/Case#location-instance_method) method, which returns a [`Cucumber::Core::Ast::Location::Precise`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cucumber-core/Cucumber/Core/Ast/Location/Precise). From that you can access the feature's file path using `#file`:

```
scenario.location.file
#=> "features/mobile/test.feature"
```

For example, the hook could look like:

```
Before do |scenario|
  platform = scenario.location.file.split(File::SEPARATOR)[1].to_sym
  #=> :admin:, :desktop or :mobile

  # Output the platform (or whatever conditional logic you want)
  case platform
  when :admin then puts 'admin'
  when :desktop then puts 'desktop'
  when :mobile then puts 'mobile'
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow, great! Justin - you are best! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ruby version 2.0 and above then the `__dir__` method is your way to go (in case you want to get the absolute path):

`# File: /home/xxx/folder/features/admin/test.rb
puts __dir__ # => "/home/xxx/folder/features/admin"`

But what if you only want to know the name of the directory where the file resides? Then you could use `File.basename`:

`# File: /home/xxx/folder/features/admin/test.rb
puts File.basename(__dir__) # => "admin"`